# Multiprocessing pool size - cpu_count or cpu_count/2?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, python-multiprocessing

I'm running python scripts that do batch data processing on fairly large aws instances (48 or 96 vCPU).  multiprocessing.Pool() works nicely: the workers have minimal communication with the main process (take a file path, return True/False).  I/O and memory don't seem to be limiting.

I've had variable performance where sometimes the best speed comes from pool size = number of vCPU, sometimes number of vCPU/2, and sometimes vCPU*some multiple around 2-4.  These are for different kinds of jobs, on different instances, so it would be hard to benchmark all of them.

Is there a rule of thumb for what size pool to use?

P.S. multiprocessing.cpu_count() returns a number that seems to be equal to the number of vCPU. If that is consistent, I'd like to pick some reasonable multiple of cpu_count and just leave it at that.

Comment: I found that if the single task doesn't use much cpu you can even choose a  multiple `m>1`  and `m * os.cpu_count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many rules-of-thumb that you may follow, depending on the task as you already figured out

- Number of *physical* cores
- Number of *logical* cores
- Number of phyiscal or logical cores *minus one* (supposedly reserving one core for the logic and control)

To avoid counting logical cores instead of physical ones, I suggest using the `psutil` library:

```py
import psutil
psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
```

As for what using in the end, for numerically intensive applications I tend to go with the number of physical cores. Bear in mind that some BLAS implementations use multithreading by default, which may hurt a lot the scalability of data-parallel pipelines. Use `MKL_NUM_THREADS=1` or `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` (depending on your BLAS backend) as environment variables whenever doing batch processing and you should have quasi-linear speedups w.r.t. the number of physical cores.

Comment: How would you use `cpu_count()` to parallelize a `for` loop which essentially reads large image files (55 total and 50 MB each) and makes titles out of them and saves? ```from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
with Pool(cpu_count()) as pool:
    list(pool.imap_unordered(tile_func, img_paths, chunksize=5))```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for those numbers:

1. number of vCPU: It is reasonable, we use all the cores.
2. number of vCPU/2: It is also reasonable, as sometimes we have double logical cores compares to the physical cores. But logical cores won't actually speed your program up, so we just use vCPU/2.
3. vCPU*some multiple around 2-4: It is reasonable for some IO-intensive tasks. For these kinds of tasks, the process is not occupying the core all the time, so we can schedule some other tasks during IO operations.

So now let's analyze the situation, I guess you are running on a server which might be a VPS. In this case, there is no difference between logical cores and physical cores, because vCPU is just an abstract computation resource provided by the VPS provider. You cannot really touch the underlying physical cores.

If your main process is not computation-intensive, or let's say it is just a simple controller, then you don't need to allocate a whole core for it, which means you don't need to minus one.

Based on your situation, I would like to suggest the number of vCPU. But you still need to decide based on the real situation you meet. The critical rule is:

**Maximize resource usage(use as many cores as you can), minimize resource competition(Too many processes will compete for the resource, which will slow the whole program down).**

Comment: How would you use `cpu_count()` to parallelize a `for` loop which essentially reads large image files (55 total and 50 MB each) and makes titles out of them and saves? ```from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
with Pool(cpu_count()) as pool:
    list(pool.imap_unordered(tile_func, img_paths, chunksize=5))```